# SUM of COUNTS MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

I have the following sql query

```
 SELECT 
(SELECT count(cid) from A where uid=45 group by cid) as cats 
(SELECT count(cid) from A where uid=45) as cats_total
```

The first sub-select produces 4 rows and counts the number of items in each cid.  The second sub-select produces only 1 row and counts the numbers of items total.

My problem lies in the second sub-select.  SQL is producing an error because they have different amounts of rows.  Is there an adjustment I can make so the second sub-select has 4 rows, or to whatever amount of rows the first sub-select produces?

UPDATE:  Let me clarify further with a table I need to produce

```
+------+------------+
| cats | cats_total |
+------+------------+
|    2 |         17 |
|    5 |         17 |
|    1 |         17 |
|    9 |         17 |
+------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, you can use `UNION ALL`,

```
SELECT SUM(totals) grandTotal
FROM
(
    SELECT count(cid) totals from A where uid=45 group by cid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(cid) totals from A where uid=45
) s
```

Comment: Can you please take another look at my clarification (I added a table), I tried your method but I just got one row of the total.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: You don't need an example to see that your suggestion clearly makes no sense. It is essentially returning the doubled total of `count(cid)` (where uid=45). I guess you meant something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a cross join of two sub queries;

```
SELECT cats, cats_total 
FROM (SELECT count(cid) as cats from A where uid=45 group by cid) as c1 
        CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT count(cid) as cats_total from A where uid=45) as c2
```

Answer (score 0):

Kaf is right.

If someone's interested here is a working version tested via jdbc to an Oracle db:

```
SELECT cats,cats_total from  
(SELECT count(cid) as cats from A where uid=45 group by cid)
cross join
(SELECT count(cid) as cats_total from A where uid=45)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
SELECT cats.total, cats_total.total from 
(SELECT count(cid) as total from A where uid=45 group by cid) as cats ,
(SELECT count(cid) as total from A where uid=45) as cats_total
```